# Integration tests with Javascript through Test::Unit and Capybara in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, capybara, integration-testing, testunit

With RSpec and Capybara, I used to write the following code to test for features in pages that had some javascript going on:

```
feature "Some Feature" do
    scenario "testing some scenario", js: true do
        # code
    end
end
```

Now, using Test::Unit with Capybara, how do I achieve the same result? 'Cause when I do `test 'checks some feature on some scenario', js: true` it doesn't seem to work.

EDIT

So, I was able to workaround with the following:

```
setup do
    Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver
end

teardown do
    Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.default_driver
end

test 'checks some feature on some scenario with javascript goin on' do
    # code
end
```

Is there any other solution without such a boilerplate code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I end up resolving that by defining a method in `test_helper.rb` that wraps the test within the capybara driver assigning:

```
def js
    Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver
    yield
    Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.default_driver
end
```

And using it like:

```
test 'checks some feature on some scenario with javascript goin on' do
    js do
        # code
    end
end
```

I read that [minitest-data](https://github.com/wojtekmach/minitest-metadata#example-with-capybara) could be of use here, but I didn't dig out any further.